# How to set background image to the left side of division?

Tags: html, css

The `div` below shows error messages now I want to add a image that would appear before error message. It will be just small error image which I want to appear on the left side of `div` so that it appears before error text. I tried to do it with background image now text is overlapping image as image is background for text. Is there any way in which error message instead of overlapping follows image.

```
<div id='er'><?php echo $er; ?></div>
<style>
#er{font-size: 14px;color:blue; background: url(img_stop.gif);
background-size: 35px 35px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/kp5a4s7h/3/)

```css
#er{
  font-size: 14px;
  color:blue;
  min-height:45px; /* so that the image will always be shown even for short error messages */
  background: transparent url(http://www.willowsigns.com/images/products/reflective-stop-sign-circular-icon-600mm-dia-Ehwf.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 5px center; /* image positioned 5px of the 0 left and centered top */
  background-size: 35px 35px;
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px 5px 5px 45px; /*giving left padding as 45, 35px for the image, and 5px on each side */
}
```

```html
<div id='er'>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores soluta accusamus dolorum ut odit voluptatem, autem sint!
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but my error messages are short so how to center text vertically. now text appears at the top of image like first line of your error message

Comment: if you are sure your error messages are *always one line*, change this `min-height` to `line-height`, check this: https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/kp5a4s7h/4/